# PHP SoapClient can't load WSDL file, but it can load others

Tags: php, soap

I know there are countless threads on this, but nothing suggested has worked for me.

When trying to create a new SoapClient, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: 
Couldn't load from 'https://m2mconnect.ee.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl' : 
failed to load external entity "https://m2mconnect.ee.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl"
```

The WSDL file is: `https://m2mconnect.ee.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl`.

I thought it might be a https issue, but I've successfully loaded other wsdl clients. It seems to just be this EE one that won't work, and it's getting very frustrating!

I'm running my application on a vagrant instance with php5.5, on a mac os x host. I've tried running it on mac os x and I get the same problem.

I've also tried setting the 'ssl_method' option for SoapClient, but that has no effect.

I've tried to curl/wget the url and it gets an SSL error, whereas it completes the handshake with something like https://paypal.com

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Update:

I ran this on the vagrant box: `curl -v -SSLv3 https://m2mconnect.ee.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl` and it connected successfully, however, creating a SoapClient with the option `ssl_method` set to `SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3` doesn't work

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344899/error-consuming-web-service-soapclient-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up forking [BeSimpleSoapClient](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoapClient) which wrapped SoapClient and uses Curl to get the SoapService. I modified their Curl class to allow setting of curl ssl version: https://github.com/robcaw/BeSimpleSoapClient

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the WSDL location right now with a browser.

So the only answer remaining is: IF you get SSL errors when trying to download the WSDL with curl or wget, then it is safe to assume PHP has the same error - and the solution would be to fix them - and as a first step, mentioning your findings in your question.

As it looks right now, PHP is not to blame, everything you did should work - the only thing missing is the network connection to fetch the WSDL.

Comment: The moment you realize that the question you have right now has been "answered" by a former "you" without having a clue...